# How to search a folder by a partial name by the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to search for all folders that have the `jdk` word contains in their full name by the command line. Is there anyway performing such a query?

I tried to look everywhere, but all results concentrates on finding only by files name such as `dir /s *foo*`.
Is there any better queries?

Comment: `dir /S /A:D "*jdk*`

Comment: Thanks. This is working but really slow when searching on the root folder. Is there any way adding another filtering to the searched name like -  Java\jdk?

Comment: That won't speed it up. It needs to read all the folders into the disk cache. If you run it a second time it will be far faster.

Comment: Yes, you can specify the directory in which to start. `DIR /S /A:D "C:\app\*jdk*"` However, this will only look under \app. It will not find anything under \Java.